# python basehttpserver: can i modify the 404 response?

Tags: python, basehttpserver

Is it possible to modify the 404 response page sent from pythons basehttpserver library?

Answer (score 3):

To modify the default error document displayed by `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`, you may customize the `error_message_format` attribute. It's a string in which you can use the following tags that will be replaced with their value when rendered:

- %(code)d is the numeric error code (eg. 404)
- %(message)s is a string representation of the error
- %(explain)s is a string with more explanations about the error

Of course you can use HTML. For instance:

```
yourBaseServerInstance.error_message_format = '''
<body>
<h1>Error!</h1>
<p>Error code %(code)d.</p>
<p>Message: %(message)s.</p>
<p>Error code explanation: %(code)s = %(explain)s.</p>
</body>'''
```

Comment: By default the content will be sent as `text/html`.  So I'd say your text *will* be handled as HTML. OTOH, if you *want* to send other type, change `error_content_type` attribute. (text/plain for plain text but virtually any MIME type if you are brave enough ;))